# IntentService <-> Activity communication

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, intentservice

One of the way to communicate between `Activity` and `IntentService` is to use `BroadcastReceiver` (or Local one) and "`sendBroadcast()`" method.

`BroadcastReceiver` is listening only when Activity is in `onResume` - `onPause` (visible lifecycle).

So what if:

1. `Activity` is created and is visible so our `BroadcastReceiver` is listening
2. we are starting new `IntentService`, this service is working in background... (for example connecting with server and checking something).
3. `Activity` starts to be invisible because someone turn off screen. So in onPause method our `BroadcastReceiver` is `unregistered`.
4. Intent service finish his task and make sendBroadcast to notify changed status or something else that activity should know.
   BUT now reciver is unregistered so this broadcast message dies.
5. User turns screen on, activity is visible again (but it has no info from intent service). Intent service message IS LOST.

How to deal with this kind of situation? If we want Activity to have info about if intentservice stopped and end his job or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to deal with this kind of situation?

You handle this the same way you handle all sorts of other situations, such as the user pressing BACK (thereby destroying the activity) and doing something in your UI to create a new instance of your activity.

Messaging from the service to the activity is a push interface, which is good for real-time updates. You *also* need a *pull* interface, where the activity can get the current status. And, in many cases, that also needs to take persistence into account, as the service, or even the entire process, may be long gone by the time a new activity instance needs to show those results.

Hence, the details will depend a lot on what the service is doing and how the UI can determine if that work is now completed and what the results are. That could involve querying a database, for example.

Comment: The main problem is this _pull_ interface.

So details in this case are:
1. Service is connecting to server to check if status of some item changed. And this `IntentService` got ability to update this status in database (Sqlite/but without `ContentProvider`).

So it will check status then change this status in database or not. And how to tell `Activity` if that activity was not visible (listening for broadcast messages) while making broadcast if this status was changed or not.

I know that activity could check database every time in `onResume` but is there any other possibility or not?

Comment: @Jedil: "I know that activity could check database every time in onResume but is there any other possibility or not?" -- `onResume()` certainly seems like a likely time. You can kick off an `AsyncTask` to look up the current status and update your UI to match.

Comment: I thought that maybe there is some better solution for this.

But if there is not, using `AsyncTaskLoader`s seems to be better than using `IntentService`.

And probably everything would be better if i would use `CursorLoaders` in Activity and `ContentProviders` as data storage/source, because if my `IntentService` will change something in storage with content provider, CursorLoader will be automatically reloaded, right?

Comment: @Jedil: "if my IntentService will change something in storage with content provider, CursorLoader will be automatically reloaded, right?" -- only if the `IntentService` uses a `ContentResolver` to perform the changes via the `ContentProvider`, and only if the `ContentProvider` itself is written properly (e.g., has the `notifyChange()` calls and such).